# Is there any way to read main application resources from quarkus extension code?

Tags: java, quarkus

**What i have**

1. `@ApplicationScoped` class with onStart method that is trying to read resource file with `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()` method;
2. `@BuildStep` with `AdditionalBeanBuildItem` that produces my `@ApplicatinScoped` class.

**What i want to do**

Get access to resource folder of application that uses my quarkus extension and read a file.

**What is my problem**

My quarkus extension can't seems to acces it (it read its own resources instead).

I guess i just need to use a different producer but i'm not sure which one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one, you should be using `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` as the ClassLoader.

Other than that, Quarkus provides a few utilities like `ClasspathUtils` and `FileUtil` that will be useful.

A great example of how all this comes together is code that allows a user to customize the banner.

See https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/2.3.0.Final/core/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkus/deployment/steps/BannerProcessor.java#L46 for all the details